# Android Sqlite shows no such table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i want to add some image uri's to the Database. my Database table has two columns  id and String Uri. The Problem is it shows No such table exist when trying to insert some Uris to Table. Here is my Code of Database Adapter Class.

```
package com.example.mystorage;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBAdapter {
// for customer registration
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_URI = "uri";


static final String DATABASE_NAME = "IMAGE_DB";

static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "temp_images1";

static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table temp_images1 (id integer       autoincrement, "
        + "uri text not null);";

final Context context;
DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)     {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_images1");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}



// //////////////////////////////////////for
// customerRegistration////////////////
// customer registration for retrieve data
public Cursor getAllImages() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_URI}, null,
            null, null, null, null);
}
public Cursor getContentimage(long id) throws SQLException {
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_URI },
            KEY_ID + "=" + id, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
// customer registration for update data
public boolean updateimages(long id, String uri) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    // args.put(KEY_ID,id);
    args.put(KEY_URI, uri);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
}

// customer registration for insert data
public long insertImages(String uri) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    //args.put(KEY_ID, id);
    args.put(KEY_URI, uri);
    long n = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args);
    //db.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args);
    return n;
}

// customer registration for remove data
public boolean deleteImages(long id) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;

}
}
```

here is My ImageAdapter class where i am calling the insert method.
mThumbs is uri Arraylist to Store the Content of Database While Retrieving.

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c, android.net.Uri uri) {
    mContext = c;
    db= new DBAdapter(mContext);
    try {
    db.open();
    db.insertImages(uri.toString());
    db.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    upadteAllImages();

       notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Uri> imageUris) {
    mContext = c;
    db= new DBAdapter(mContext);
    try {
    db.open();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageUris.size(); i++){
    db.insertImages(imageUris.get(i).toString());
    }
    db.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    upadteAllImages();

       notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void upadteAllImages() {
    mTHumbs.clear();

    try{
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllImages();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.moveToNext()){
                String uri = c.getString(1);
                mTHumbs.add(Uri.parse(uri));
            }
        }
        //mTHumbs.add((Uri) db.getAllImages());

        db.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look of my answer

Comment: it's not Working i tried. still insert returns -1.

Comment: Still getting table not found?or something else?

Comment: the same error.. No Such Table exist

Comment: If you have no any restriction than use OrmLiteSqliteDB which is very easy

Comment: initially it was 1 then i increased it to 2 but, thats not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fix the syntax error in your `CREATE TABLE`. `AUTOINCREMENT` can only be used with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and you're missing the `PRIMARY KEY`.
2. Remove the try-catch in your `onCreate()` so that you get an exception in case of a syntax problem.
3. Uninstall your app so that the old database is removed and your helper `onCreate()` gets run again with the fixed SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE  + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_URI + " TEXT not null "+)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Some minor changes are required to create a table in database.

Please see this-

```
" CREATE TABLE temp_images1 ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + "uri TEXT NOT NULL ) ; ";
```